# Substring indexOf problem in same character

Tags: c#

Example :
[image]

I want to get the "2" character behind "- 60000 rupiah".
So i tried to code it with substring :

```
string s = "Ayam Bakar - 30000 x 2 - 60000 rupiah";
string qtyMenu = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("x") + 1, s.IndexOf("-") - 1);
```

But the substring end index didn't work properly. Maybe because the sentences have multiple "-" character. Is it possible to get different index of same character in that senteces ?

Comment: Many ways but simplest based on your needs: `string qty = s.Split("-")[1].Split("x")[1].Trim();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily achieve this by following technique:

```
string s = "Ayam Bakar - 30000 x 2 - 60000 rupiah";
string qtyMenu = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("x") + 1, (s.LastIndexOf("-")) - (s.IndexOf("x") + 1));
```

For the second parameter, the length of the the string to extract is determined by the last index of `-` minus the index of `x`

Answer (score 4):

This is a good situation for `Regex`

```
string s = "Ayam Bakar - 30000 x 2 - 60000 rupiah";

// "x" followed by (maybe) whitespaces followed by at least one digit followed by (maybe) whitespaces followed by "-".
// Capture the digits with the (...)
var match = Regex.Match(s, @"x\s*(\d+)\s*\-");

if (match.Success)
{
    // Groups[1] is the captured group
    string foo = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the message, I can derive the template format:
"{Product Name} - {Price x Qty} - {Subtotal}"

So you can implement this solution:

```
// Split message by '-'
var messages = s.Split('-');

// Result: messages[0] = "Ayam Bakar"
// Result: messages[1] = " 30000 x 2 "
// Result: messages[2] = " 60000 rupiah"

// Obtain {Price x Qty} in messages[1] and get the value after 'x'
var qtyMenu = messages[1].Substring(messages[1].IndexOf("x") + 1).Trim();
```